# timestamp being changed to 0 on import to mysql db, from csv

Tags: mysql, csv, import, timestamp

Ive got some data which was exported from a mysql database into a csv, i now want to re import this data into a mysql db.

All the other fields come in correct apart from the timestamps which are coming in as `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Below are screenshots of the data 1) as a CSV and 2) after import into the mysql db (as viewed with sequel pro)

Any idea how i can resolve this ?

[image: csv import]

[image: sequel post import]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the charset of your database, the default locale, language and table structure this is not a complete answer. However, Problem could be in the formatting and delimiter used in the incoming date field in csv. The format in the csv should follow the expected database format i.e. 2013-05-24 23:59:59 (what is shown seems to be 24/05/2013 23:59:59) for example updating the forward slash (/) to - as well as arranging the date fields as expected by the default format of your database or defined by the table. Also review you default date format expected by the data to be put in the table